# when does $ \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{dx}{(1+|x|^2)^{k/2}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

When does the following integral converges?
I am wondering the condition of $k$ on which the integral
$$
 \int_{\mathbb R^n} \frac{dx}{(1+|x|^2)^{k/2}}
$$
converges. Here the dimension $n=1,2,3,\cdots$.

Comment: What have you tried here, and where are you stuck? Please note that this is not a forum to have your homework solved without work. The community here expects you to try a problem before posting it, and to let us know your thoughts on the same, so we can best direct the explanations.

Comment: I advise  you to check first for the case of  $n=1$, then try to generalize the result to the case  $n \geq 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewriting the integral in polar coordinates, you get
$$I_{n,k}=S_n\int_0^\infty \frac{r^{n-1}}{(1+r^2)^{k/2}}\mathrm dr,$$
where $S_n$ is the $(n-1)$-volume of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^d$ (for instance $S_2=2\pi$, $S_3=4\pi$...). 
The integrand is equivalent to $r^{n-1-k}$ when $r\to\infty$. So the integral converges if and only if $n-1-k<-1$ or 
$$\boxed{n<k}.$$